# Format JSON string

Tags: javascript, json

I have this string in JSON format:

```
"message": "<?= __('I agree to the <a>Terms of Service</a>', $block->getUrl('terms-conditions')) ?>"
```

What I want to do is add a link to the string of this form

```
 "message": "<?= __('I agree to the <a href="%1">Terms of Service</a>', $block->getUrl('terms-conditions')) ?>"
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON
```

How can I add the link to the  tag in a correct way?

Comment: Don't use a template to generate JSON. Build your data structure and then run it through JSON.stringify.

Comment: Escape quotes in href. `\"%1\"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the double quotes in the string like:

```
 "message": "<?= __('I agree to the <a href=\"%1\">Terms of Service</a>', $block->getUrl('terms-conditions')) ?>"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have any string, it's best to just convert it to json, the function will handle all your characters that require escaping.

In php it can look like this:

```
"message": <?= json_encode(__('I agree to the <a>Terms of Service</a>', $block->getUrl('terms-conditions'))) ?>
```

each language should have similar json encode function, just search in google for you language.